# How to implement IAmsiStream to support running a malware scan on windows on a stream

Tags: c#, windows-defender, antimalware

When implementing an [IAmsiStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/amsi/nn-amsi-iamsistream) to perform a scan with Windows Defender, on files larger than ~20MBs it fails with `Value does not fall within the expected range.`.

What is missing from this implementation?

```cs
    public class AmsiStream : IAmsiStream
    {
        private readonly Stream _input;
        private readonly string _name;
        private static readonly byte[] _nullPtr = new byte[Marshal.SizeOf(IntPtr.Zero)];

        public AmsiStream(Stream input, string name)
        {
            _input = input ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(input));
            _name = name ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
        }

        public int GetAttribute(AMSI_ATTRIBUTE attribute, int dataSize, byte[] data, out int retData)
        {
            const int E_NOTIMPL = unchecked((int)0x80004001);
            const int E_NOT_SUFFICIENT_BUFFER = unchecked((int)0x8007007A);

            byte[] bytes = { };
            int retValue = 0;

            switch (attribute)
            {

                case AMSI_ATTRIBUTE.AMSI_ATTRIBUTE_APP_NAME:
                    bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("TestAmsi" + "\0");
                    break;
                case AMSI_ATTRIBUTE.AMSI_ATTRIBUTE_CONTENT_NAME:
                    bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(_name + "\0");
                    break;
                case AMSI_ATTRIBUTE.AMSI_ATTRIBUTE_CONTENT_SIZE:
                    bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes((ulong)_input.Length);
                    break;
                case AMSI_ATTRIBUTE.AMSI_ATTRIBUTE_SESSION:
                    bytes = _nullPtr;
                    break;
                case AMSI_ATTRIBUTE.AMSI_ATTRIBUTE_CONTENT_ADDRESS:
                    retValue = E_NOTIMPL;
                    break;
                default:
                    retValue = E_NOTIMPL;
                    break;
            }

            retData = 0;
            if (retValue == 0)
            {
                retData = bytes.Length;
                if (dataSize < bytes.Length)
                    return E_NOT_SUFFICIENT_BUFFER;

                Array.Copy(bytes, data, bytes.Length);
            }

            return retValue;

        }

        public int Read(long position, int size, byte[] buffer, out int readSize)
        {
            _input.Seek(position, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            readSize = _input.Read(buffer, 0, size);
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

A test case is :

```cs
        [Fact]
        public void TestWithLargeFile()
        {
            const long k = 1024;
            const long m = 1024 * k;
            const long fileSize = 21 * m;
            var c = new Random(42);
            var fileBuffer = new byte[fileSize];

            c.NextBytes(fileBuffer);
            Equal(AMSI_RESULT.AMSI_RESULT_CLEAN, ScanInternal(new MemoryStream(fileBuffer), "test.file.txt"));
        }

        private AMSI_RESULT ScanInternal(Stream streamToCheck, string fileName)
        {
            var scanner = (IAntiMalware)new CAntiMalware();
            var stream = new AmsiStream(streamToCheck, fileName);
            var result = scanner.Scan(stream, out AMSI_RESULT scanResult, out IAntiMalwareProvider _);

            if (result != (ulong)HResult.S_OK)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Malware scan returned not OK: {result}");
            }

            return scanResult;
        }
```

Full source code for this test at [this github repo](https://github.com/brunomlopes/AmsiStreamScanIssue)

Comment: You should handle `AMSI_ATTRIBUTE_CONTENT_ADDRESS` when the content is fully loaded into memory, see this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/amsi/nf-amsi-iamsistream-getattribute#remarks).

Comment: IAmsiStream implementations should not load the entire content into memory, as it might not fit. The goal is to stream data.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can *stream* a large file to Windows Defender provider. As per this [github thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/issues/62), there seems to be a limit implemented by the platform that if you don't handle `AMSI_ATTRIBUTE_CONTENT_ADDRESS` in `GetAttribute`, the maximum buffer size passed in the `Read` method is 16MB. And the purpose of the `Read` method is not streaming, instead it

> Requests a buffer-full of content to be read.

The [sample code (C++)](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/main/Samples/AmsiStream/AmsiStream.cpp) provided by Microsoft can't handle files that are larger than this size limit either.

The [Microsoft developer docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/amsi/dev-audience) declared:

> AMSI is designed in particular to combat "fileless malware"

which

> exists exclusively as a computer memory-based artifact

as per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fileless_malware).

To me, if the file size is larger than 16MB, you could load it into memory and return the buffer address by handling `AMSI_ATTRIBUTE_CONTENT_ADDRESS`. And for large files, you could consider using a [memory mapped file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile?view=net-5.0):

```
public unsafe int GetAttribute(AMSI_ATTRIBUTE attribute, int dataSize,
    [Out]byte[] data, [Out]out int retData)
{
    ...
    case AMSI_ATTRIBUTE_CONTENT_ADDRESS:

        retData = sizeof(IntPtr);

        if (dataSize < retData)
        {
            return E_NOT_SUFFICIENT_BUFFER;
        }

        // This is an example
        // Better to open in constructor and close in Dispose
        var mappedFile = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(_name, FileMode.Open);
        var mappedFileAccessor = mappedFile.CreateViewAccessor(0, fileSize);

        byte* fileContent = null;
        mappedFileAccessor.SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle.AcquirePointer(ref fileContent);

        fixed (byte* pData = data)
        {
            *(IntPtr*) pData = (IntPtr)fileContent;
        }

        return 0;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Unclear if you can exceed 20MB using the COM flavor of AMSI, but it appears you can using the vanilla Win32 functions by using the same session handle from `AmsiOpenSession` in successive calls to `AmsiScanBuffer`.  Will post an answer demonstrating this; this comment is a reminder to myself to do so.

Answer (score -1):

Instead use MalwareScanner from: https://github.com/NewOrbit/MalwareScan.AMSI

`var scanner = new MalwareScanner("MyApplications Viruscanner"); var result = scanner.HasVirus(stream, filename);`

or for scanning an incoming large file bytes segment by bytes segment see:

WindowsCOMAntiMalware: https://github.com/bsmg/BeatSaber-IPA-Reloaded/blob/master/IPA.Loader/AntiMalware/_HideInNet3/WindowsCOMAntiMalware.cs

with 2 IAmsiStream implementations:

AmsiMemoryStream: https://github.com/bsmg/BeatSaber-IPA-Reloaded/blob/master/IPA.Loader/AntiMalware/_HideInNet3/ComAPI/AmsiMemoryStream.cs
AmsiFileStream: https://github.com/bsmg/BeatSaber-IPA-Reloaded/blob/master/IPA.Loader/AntiMalware/_HideInNet3/ComAPI/AmsiFileStream.cs

P.S.: the 16mb limit is nowhere to be found in the official docs, I don't think is a IAmsiStream limitation, the IAmsiStream is passed to the IAntimalwareProvider which is a vendor implementation and maybe the problem lays there; you should try another vendor to see if you get the same error:

- Eset: https://help.eset.com/ees/6/en-US/index.html?idh_config_antivirus.htm
- AVG: https://malwaretips.com/threads/avg-antimalware-scan-interface.56180/
- Kaspersky: https://support.kaspersky.com/KESWin/11.1.0/en-US/174819.htm

Comment: https://github.com/NewOrbit/MalwareScan.AMSI/blob/master/src/MalwareScan.AMSI/MalwareScanner.cs#L157

This copies the entire stream into a bytebuffer. For larger files this is a non-starter.

Comment: @BrunoLopes if I understand correctly, you want to scan an incoming large file bytes segment by bytes segment. I have updated the answer, please take a look